# Default Country of Manufacture Value

Tags: magento-1.9

how can I set the default Country of Manufacture field value to United States whenever I create a new product?

I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

go to

Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes

search for Country of manufacturer

click on it

and the click the second tab "Manage Label/Options"

check the "Is Default" Radio button on Country of Manufacturer
sample : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euvrc.png

Comment: I followed your steps, it doesn't work or I might be doing something wrong, I also flushed the cache.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lF7DNv8.png

Comment: @cubaton3 please provide screenshot fo your manufacturer attributes second tab "Manage Label/Options". show I will check and help you.

Comment: These are my Manufacturer attributes, but I need it for Country of Manufacture, not Manufacturers, http://i.imgur.com/HOXIslm.png